# how yo get the torch.mode 's output indeces , can details

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
>>> b
tensor([[ 6,  7, 12,  7,  8],
        [ 0,  1,  6,  1,  2],
        [ 0,  1,  6,  1,  2],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [10, 11, 16, 11, 12],
        [-1,  0,  5,  0,  1],
        [-2, -1,  4, -1,  0],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 1,  2,  7,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  2,  7,  2,  3],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6, 11,  6,  7],
        [-2, -1,  4, -1,  0],
        [-3, -2,  3, -2, -1],
        [-5, -4,  1, -4, -3],
        [ 1,  2,  7,  2,  3],
        [12, 13, 18, 13, 14],
        [-3, -2,  3, -2, -1],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 3,  4,  9,  4,  5],
        [10, 11, 16, 11, 12],
        [-6, -5,  0, -5, -4],
        [ 9, 10, 15, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 18, 13, 14],
        [-3, -2,  3, -2, -1],
        [-2, -1,  4, -1,  0],
        [-4, -3,  2, -3, -2],
        [-1,  0,  5,  0,  1],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 4,  5, 10,  5,  6],
        [-1,  0,  5,  0,  1],
        [ 5,  6, 11,  6,  7],
        [ 7,  8, 13,  8,  9],
        [ 3,  4,  9,  4,  5],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 4,  5, 10,  5,  6],
        [-4, -3,  2, -3, -2],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [-1,  0,  5,  0,  1],
        [ 2,  3,  8,  3,  4],
        [ 4,  5, 10,  5,  6],
        [ 9, 10, 15, 10, 11],
        [-1,  0,  5,  0,  1],
        [-4, -3,  2, -3, -2],
        [ 0,  1,  6,  1,  2],
        [ 4,  5, 10,  5,  6],
        [ 6,  7, 12,  7,  8],
        [-2, -1,  4, -1,  0]])
>>> torch.mode(b, 0)
torch.return_types.mode(
values=tensor([2, 3, 8, 3, 4]),
indices=tensor([20, 20, 20, 20, 20]))
```

i don't know why indeces is all equal to 20

the details of torch.mode description as below
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mode.html#torch.mode

torch.mode(input, dim=- 1, keepdim=False, *, out=None)
Returns a namedtuple (values, indices) where values is the mode value of each row of the input tensor in the given dimension dim, i.e. a value which appears most often in that row, and indices is the index location of each mode value found.

By default, dim is the last dimension of the input tensor.

If keepdim is True, the output tensors are of the same size as input except in the dimension dim where they are of size 1. Otherwise, dim is squeezed (see torch.squeeze()), resulting in the output tensors having 1 fewer dimension than input.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the way the tensor `b` is. The row `[2, 3, 8, 3, 4]` is repeated a lot, so in each column the modes are respectively `[2, 3, 8, 3, 4]` and more importantly, the mode indices will be equal precisely because the modes occur together; if you look at the row with index 20 (i.e., the 21st row), it is exactly `[2, 3, 8, 3, 4]`.

I am assuming that you constructed `b` similar to  the example in [`torch.mode`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mode.html#torch.mode) which I believe is a poor choice for an example as it leads to confusion like the one you are having.

Instead, consider the following:

```py
>>> b = torch.randint(4, (5, 7))
>>> b
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
        [0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2]])
>>> torch.mode(b, 0)
torch.return_types.mode(
values=tensor([0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]),
indices=tensor([1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4]))
```

In the above, `b` has different modes in each column which are respectively `[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]` and the indices returned by `torch.mode` are `[1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4]`. This makes sense because, for example, in the first column, 0 is the most common element and there is a 0 at index 1. Similarly, in the second column, 2 is the most common element and there is a 2 at index 3. This is true for all columns. If you want the modes of the rows instead, you would do `torch.mode(b, 1)`.